# How to re add elements in array to their same position on stage?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash

Hey everyone so in my game I am creating I add all my interactive objects to the stage by simply dragging from the library and placing them on the stage. Then in Flash Develop in my Engine Class I place them inside an array like so:

```
private var aZebraArray:Array;
```

In my constructor I add the elements on the stage through their instance names I gave them Like so:

```
aZebraArray = [startScreen.zebra_Front, startScreen.zebra_Middle, startScreen.zebra_Back, startScreen.zebra_Far];
```

Then in my Enter_Frame Listener I loop through the objects on stage like so for the Hit Test:

```
private function Round_1Controls():void 
    {
        trace(aZebraArray.length);
        for (var i:int = 0; i < aZebraArray.length; i++)
        {
            var currentZebra = aZebraArray[i];

            if (crosshair.bullet.hitTestObject(currentZebra) && shotGun)
            {
                trace("HIT");

                aZebraArray.splice(i, 1);
                currentZebra.gotoAndPlay("DIE");
                shotGun = false;

                //Add points
                nPoints += 50;
                updatePointsText();

                //Animals hit for stars
                animalsHit ++;
            }

        }
```

Now in my game if the player doesn't get 3 stars he is able to Retry and restart that round over. The **PROBLEM** That I have run into is that I don't quite know how I would go about having the objects that are on stage placed back where they first started from because when the round starts the "Zebras" run across the stage through a custom tween I made in each  of them. Also I believe I could just create a new array like so:

```
aZebraArray = new Array();
aZebraArray = [startScreen.zebra_Front, startScreen.zebra_Middle, startScreen.zebra_Back, startScreen.zebra_Far];
```

but then how could i restart all their animations so they can run across the stage again? I know I can just create their own class and add them in array then control them through a timer object but I add them manually on stage because their are a lot of bushes that they need to hide behind or be in front of and to code that would be exhausting. If anyone can help I would Appreciate it thanks!

Here is what I have in my retry Function but it is only adding 1 or 2 of the objects in the array back to the stage.

```
private function replayRound_1(e:MouseEvent):void 
    {
        continueScreen.mcRetry.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, replayRound_1);
        continueScreen.destroyContinueScreen();
        round1 = true;
        nAmmo = 0;
        nAmmo += 5;
        updateAmmoText();
        animalsHit = 0;
        hasAmmo = true;
        gameChannel = gameSound.play(0, 999);

        //aZebraArray = [];
        aZebraArray = new Array();
        aZebraArray = [startScreen.zebra_Front, startScreen.zebra_Middle, startScreen.zebra_Back, startScreen.zebra_Far];

        for (var i:int = 0; i < aZebraArray.length; i++)
        {
            var currentZebra = aZebraArray[i];

            currentZebra.gotoAndStop("RUN");
        }
    }
```

Comment: An aside, doing `aZebraArray = new Array()` creates an array.  doing `aZebraArray = [item...]` creates a new array as well (so the one right before it has no purpose and can be removed).   You should use a `Vector` instead (it's an Array only all members have to be of the specified type), so you could do `private var aZebraArray:Vector<MovieClip> = new Vector<MovieClip>();`   They are faster and give you better compile time checking

Comment: It doesn't look like you are adding/removing anything from the stage.  I'm assuming that when you `gotoAndPlay("DIE")` that it is the equivalent of removing it?

Comment: Are you certain you don't want to do `gotoAndPlay("RUN")` instead of `gotoAndStop`? -   not knowing the nature of your zebra objects makes it hard to answer this.

Comment: Another issue you may run into, is the ramifications of splicing an array your are currently iterating forwards through.  You should iterate backwards to avoid messing your index up.   See my detailed answer to this question to know more:   http://stackoverflow.com/a/30633276/1457439

Comment: Hey thanks for the information @BadFeelingAboutThis. I never knew that about adding elements to an array is the same as new array. I am only used to creating an array and pushing a class into it not dealing with objects on stage. Also gotoAndStop did the trick. I will def check that out. Seeing as this is going to be a mobile app I need to focus on Performance. Thanks again man I appreciate everything

Comment: Best tips for performance, is make your ENTER FRAME handler as efficient as possible.   avoid using the `var` keyword in it at all (create private vars outside the function),  and use as few `.`'s as possible.

Comment: When you say `gotoAndStop` did the trick, what do you mean?

Comment: Interesting. Use as few "." what do you mean? Like ".gotoAndPlay" ".hitTestObject"?  I mean when ever I used gotoAndPlay it wouldn't restart the tween. For some reason I think its how I am coding everything when I use gotoAndStop it resets and plays it over. weird.

Comment: when I say "." I mean if you have say `object.object.property`  and are accessing that property a lot , it's ever so slightly faster to just create a local var of `var prop = object.object.property;` instead of continually accessing properties of properties.   Keeping in mind that the var should be declared at a point when performance isn't critical (eg not in a for loop or frame handler)

Comment: In regards to arrays,  doing `= [item, item, item]` creates a new array (with the supplied items) and is *exactly* the same as `= new Array(item, item, item)`.  to add items to an existing array, you use the array's push method:  `myArray.push(item, item, item);`

Comment: Oh okay I Understand now anything helps when it comes to mobile performance. That is perfect thank you man I was about to ask how to push new items into the array for my harder levels. Thanks you have been amazing. How long have you been coding AS3 for?

Comment: I started when there was just AS1 in the late 90's.   In the real world, your performance will come down to how you handle graphics.  Stay away from vectors unless they are dead simple,  export with GPU acceleration, and if you get lots of graphics, consider using something like starlight (or other framework that taps into the AS3 Stage3D api)

Comment: That is awesome. Yeah don't mess with vectors at all. Thanks for all the advice.